# Read file and display 3rd line

Tags: php

I am trying to read urls from a file and display 3rd line.
can't access an array element directly.
each line has one url on it in the file and there are one url per line, 20 lines.

```
$urls = file('urls.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

//doesn't work
echo "test:".$urls[3]."<br>";

//works fine
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    echo $url."<br>";
}
```

Comment: you missing 's' in $url[3] variable

Comment: each line has 1 url on it and nothing else
1 url per line with 20 lines in file.

Comment: sorry the missing s was a typo posting it here. the $urls[3] is in my code

Comment: Well file() reads contents of a file into an array based on new line character and you are ignoring that with this flag. FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES

Comment: What do you get if you var_dump($urls); ?

Comment: my interpretation is that flag just removes the new line from the line in the array.
I tried it both ways and didn't work.

Comment: Ok, can you please show what var_dump($urls) looks like?

Comment: Array indexes start at 0. The third line is `$urls[2]`.

Comment: @EdNewman Your interpretation is correct.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a sufficient description of the problem. In what way does it not work? Be specific.